# How to pass a var type to a method C#

Tags: c#

I 've a doubt that researching I couldn't solve.
I want to pass a parameter using a var type to this method:

```
public static List<T[]> sortRequests<T>(List<T> _requests)
{


    return null;
}
```

And I am calliinf the method here:

```
//Note: Thats code corresponds from an HttpRest service.

var _requests = await _requestService.Search(new SearchRequestSpecificationMapper().Map(searchRequestsViewModel));
var requests = sortRequests(_requests);
```

So VS 2015 is reporting about an error when I call the sortRequest() method. 
Can anybody help me please?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What is your error?  Also `var` is not a type.  It uses type inference to determine the actual type from the assigned value or expression.

Comment: "VS 2015 is reporting about an error " could you be a little more specific?

Comment: Please can you be clear on what the type of `_requests` is as well - call `_requests.GetType().FullName`, or just hold your cursor over it in Visual Studio.

Comment: `var` is not a type. It's just shorthand for the inferred type that's returned from the right hand side of the assignment. In your case, it's whatever type `Search` returns. If `Search` does not return a `List<T>`, then the call to `sortRequests` will fail.

Answer (score 2):

`_requests` is (presumably) not a `List<T>`.

You *might* be able to make it into a `List<T>` by caling `ToList`:

```
var requests = sortRequests(_requests.ToList());
```

However, I can't be certain without knowing more about your code, especially what the `Search` and `Map` functions do.

**NOTE**
Please be aware that there is no such thing as a `var type` in C#. `var` is just a bit of syntactic sugar that means "This variable has the type of whatever I assign to it when I declare it" - it's no different to just declaring it as the correct type.

Comment: As you´re just guessing this will probably not be an actual answer, merely a comment.

Comment: @HimBromBeere This was a bit long for a comment. Also, I bet £20 I'm right ;)